# Pointers in a doubly linked list not working correctly

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I want to generate a random doubly linked list with a fixed length that is chosen by the user.

The list would insert the first value at the head and then all of the other values at the end of the list but it doesn't correctly adjust the pointers.

Head and tail nodes are both initialized in main to `NULL`.

Random values work, the problem is with the pointers since at the second iteration the tail stays the same as the head, meaning the list is not increasing.

```
void GenRandSeq(struct Node* &head, struct Node* &tail, int len){
    int i = 0;

    std::mt19937 rng;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> uint_dist(0,10000);

    while (i < len){
        Node* newNode = new Node();
        int new_el = uint_dist(rng);
        newNode->key = new_el;
        newNode->prev = NULL;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL){

            tail = newNode;
            head = newNode;
        }

        else{

            if (tail != NULL){
                newNode->next = NULL;
                newNode->prev = tail;
                tail->next = newNode;
            }
            else
                tail = newNode;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

I don't see what I'm missing in the code.

Comment: Did you check head and tail are null during the function invocation?

Comment: Note `if (tail != NULL)` is useless, tail cannot be NULL if head is not NULL, or that means the call is wrong. But tail must be updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You are not setting `tail` correctly.

When `head` and `tail` are both not null (which should always be true when the list is not empty), you are not updating the `tail` to point at the newly created node. The assignment of `tail` needs to be moved out of the `else` statement. You are appending new nodes to the end of the list, so the `tail` *must* be updated on *every* loop iteration.

Try something more like this instead:

```
void GenRandSeq(Node* &head, Node* &tail, int len){
    std::mt19937 rng;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> uint_dist(0,10000);

    while (len > 0){
        Node* newNode = new Node;
        newNode->key = uint_dist(rng);
        newNode->prev = tail;
        newNode->next = nullptr;
        if (!head){
            head = newNode;
        }
        if (tail){
            tail->next = newNode;
        }
        tail = newNode;
        --len;
    }
}
```

Which can then be streamlined a little bit further by eliminating the `if` statements inside the loop:

```
void GenRandSeq(Node* &head, Node* &tail, int len){
    std::mt19937 rng;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> uint_dist(0,10000);

    Node **next = (tail) ? &(tail->next) : &head;

    while (len > 0){
        Node *newNode = new Node;
        newNode->key = uint_dist(rng);
        newNode->prev = tail;
        newNode->next = nullptr;
        *next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        next = &(newNode->next);
        --len;
    }
}
```